# Is there a faster way to render paths onto an UIImage than UIGraphicsImageRenderer?

Tags: ios, image, render

I want to display a map in my iOS application. Therefor, I got a floorplan image (UIImage) and use the following code to render paths (which represent the buildings or rooms) onto the map image:

```
static func draw(paths: [[CGPoint]], toImage image: UIImage?) -> UIImage? {
    if let image = image {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size)
        return renderer.image { context in
            image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.init(white: 0.1, alpha: 0.5).cgColor)
            for path in paths {
                if path.count > 2 {
                    context.cgContext.move(to: path[0])
                    for point in path {
                        context.cgContext.addLine(to: point)
                    }
                    context.cgContext.addLine(to: path[0])
                }
            }
            context.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The result of this method is then set to an UIImageView. However, this takes about two seconds, so way too long.

I am new to iOS development and this was the only way I found.

Does anyone know a faster way? Maybe using custom views or something?

Comment: There are a few things you can do to simplify and optimize the code (for example using `addPath` instead of recreating the paths one line segment at a time) but I think the more interesting question is if you need to render the paths to an image or if there is another solution all together. What are you doing with the rendered image? Just displaying it in the UI?

Comment: Also, how large is the image you are rendering the paths over? Roughly how many paths are there in the array and how complex are they (roughly how many lines do they each contain)?

Comment: yes it is just displayed in a scroll view so it can be moved around and zoomed. The images are never larger than 1920x1080 and there are no more than 10 paths with up to 5 lines each

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a look at `CAShapeLayer`, it is usually quite fast, although I can't say if it outperforms `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` in your case. My guess is that it will, because it also scales as needed, so removes the need to create a large image.

In case you are new to layers, they are like views except they don't have a user input part. They are easy to work with, since every `UIView` actually have a `.layer` for its rendering, which also can be used as a layer parent.

To make a layer work with a view, you just add it to your views layer property as a sub-layer, and then make sure it has the right size. Best way to size the layer is either by using the layers `.contentsGravity` or to set it manually in the views `layoutSubviews`.

[Read more about CAShapeLayer in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer?language=swift)

[A tutorial on layers](https://www.raywenderlich.com/169004/calayer-tutorial-ios-getting-started)